# How to translate HttpResponse JSON to Java 17 record directly

Tags: java, java-17, java-http-client, java-record

I am sending a HTTP REST GET request to an API with standard Java 17 like this :

`HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());`

and I can see the with response.body() the correct JSON.
I want to translate it directly to a Java record like this:

`record GetBearerTokenRespone(String access_token, String expires_in, String token_type)`

However, I do not see anything build in the standard library to do so and one have to use external libraries, for example like described here *https://openjdk.org/groups/net/httpclient/recipes.html* with Jackson.

Comment: Serialization and hence deserialization of Records with native [implementation differs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/records-serialization.html) from that of an actual class. Are you serializing a record entity and passing it as a response from the HTTP client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is no direct way provided by Java HttpClient to do that [details for BodyHandlerClass](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.html)

This could solved your problem using jackson:

```
HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper() .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
GetBearerTokenRespone record = mapper.readValue(response.body(), GetBearerTokenRespone.class);
```

Comment: Yes, it works the way you wrote it but only with Jackson after version 12 as described here: https://carloschac.in/2021/03/04/jacksonrecords/
Otherwise, the mapping is not direct